# On the product of relatively prime number $< N$

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, asymptotics

Let $FI(N)$ denote the product of all $\phi(N)$ [relatively prime numbers $<N$] . And define $SFI(N)$ as the product of remaining $N-\phi(N)$ numbers $\le N$ (Which are not relatively prime to $N$)

Then I have the following questions

**Q-1** For what values of $N$, $FI(N)<SFI(N) ?$
**Q-2** For what values of $N$, $d[FI(N)]<d[SFI(N)] ?$ Where $d(n)$ is number of divisors.

**Q-3** Are there asymptotics for $FI(N)$ and $SFI(N)?$

Comment: @IgorRivin   What about $SFI(N)$?

Comment: Since $SFI(N) \times FI(N) = N!,$ I am not sure what you mean...

Comment: @IgorRivin I understood your point . Now can you please tell me about asymptotics of a functions $A(N)$ which is  the sum of all ϕ(N) and $B(N)$  the sum of remaining N−ϕ(N) ?

Comment: The asymptotics of $\sum_1^N\phi(n)$ would be a good question for math.stackexchange.com, provided it doesn't duplicate a question already asked there. But it is also answered in many introductory Number Theory textbooks, and probably on a great many websites, as well.